# Prove that f∈Θ(g)if and only ifO(f) =O(g).

Tags: solution-verification

I know that big O is used to describe the upper bound of a function, so doesn't this mean that if the upper bounds f and g are the same, they are the same function? If this is the case, then we can say that  f ∈ Θ(g) because if that were not the case, then the two upper bounds would not be the same and thus one would out grow the other. Is this correct?

Comment: mb im new to stack exchange

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (:

Comment: Why are you vandalizing your own question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP keeps vandalizing it for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they need not be the same function: $O(5x^2)=O(x^2+x+7)$, for instance (and $5x^2\in\Theta(x^2+x+7)$).

You’re going to have to use the actual definitions of $O$ and $\Theta$; I’ll get you started. The definitions are given in slightly different forms in different sources, so I may be doing things a little differently from what you’re used to.

Suppose that $O(f)=O(g)$. Certainly $f\in O(f)$, so $f\in O(g)$. This means that there are constants $a_f$ and $c_f>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le c_f|g(x)|$ for all $x\ge a_f$. Similarly, $g\in O(g)$, so $g\in O(f)$, and therefore there are constants $a_g$ and $c_g>0$ such that $|g(x)|\le c_g|f(x)|$ for all $x\ge a_g$. Can you put these facts together to show that $f\in\Theta(g)$?

The proof in the other direction basically just reverses the argument.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I guess I was saying that f and g would be the same function because in computer science we drop constants and non dominant terms from functions. So in your example, the functions f(5^2) and g(^2++7) would both reduce down to x^2. That's why I said they are the same function. However, I am still probably wrong in assuming it is ok to reduce these functions in such a manner in this proof.

Comment: @PatrickPerkins: Yes, for this proof you want to treat $f$ and $g$ as specific functions, even though we know, for instance, that if $f$ is a polynomial in $x$ of degree $n$, then $O(f)=O(x^n)$, and that $O(2^n+f(x))=O(2^n)$. This theorem is actually what justifies those equalities.

Answer (score 0):

$O(f)=O(g)$ means, that they are equal sets, so $\phi \in O(f) \Leftrightarrow \phi \in O(g)$ which is $|\phi| \leqslant C_1 |f| \Leftrightarrow |\phi| \leqslant C_2 |g|$. Because $f \in O(f)=O(g)$, then $f \in O(g)$, also $g \in O(f)$. Now if we take $f,g$ in place of $\phi$, then we obtain $f \in \Theta(g)$.

Now suppose $f \in \Theta(g)$, so we have $C_1|g| \leqslant |f| \leqslant C_2|g|$. If $\phi \in O(f)$, then $|\phi| \leqslant C_3|f|\leqslant C_3C_2|g| $ and so $\phi \in O(g)$, so $O(f) \subset O(g)$. Analogical way gives $O(g) \subset O(f)$.